# Terraform import of EC2 instance always replaces on ephemeral devices and ipv6

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to figure out how to import an EC2 instance into Terraform. Whenever I import the instance, if I run "terraform plan" it always wants to replace the instance.

I have tried an extremely minimal import that just has the AMI id and instance size, and I have tried a complete import where every possible value is specified. Neither seem to work, with the same results.

The initial state:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-85 terraform]$ ls
provider.aws.tf  test1.tf

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-85 terraform]$ cat provider.aws.tf
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-west-1"
}

[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-85 terraform]$ cat test1.tf
resource "aws_instance" "web" {
  ami           = "ami-0bbc25e23a7640b9b"
  instance_type = "t3.medium"
}
```

Plan:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-85 terraform]$ terraform plan
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.


------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_instance.web will be created
  + resource "aws_instance" "web" {
      + ami                          = "ami-0bbc25e23a7640b9b"
      + arn                          = (known after apply)
      + associate_public_ip_address  = (known after apply)
      + availability_zone            = (known after apply)
      + cpu_core_count               = (known after apply)
      + cpu_threads_per_core         = (known after apply)
      + get_password_data            = false
      + host_id                      = (known after apply)
      + id                           = (known after apply)
      + instance_state               = (known after apply)
      + instance_type                = "t3.medium"
      + ipv6_address_count           = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_addresses               = (known after apply)
      + key_name                     = (known after apply)
      + network_interface_id         = (known after apply)
      + password_data                = (known after apply)
      + placement_group              = (known after apply)
      + primary_network_interface_id = (known after apply)
      + private_dns                  = (known after apply)
      + private_ip                   = (known after apply)
      + public_dns                   = (known after apply)
      + public_ip                    = (known after apply)
      + security_groups              = (known after apply)
      + source_dest_check            = true
      + subnet_id                    = (known after apply)
      + tenancy                      = (known after apply)
      + volume_tags                  = (known after apply)
      + vpc_security_group_ids       = (known after apply)

      + ebs_block_device {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_name           = (known after apply)
          + encrypted             = (known after apply)
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + snapshot_id           = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = (known after apply)
          + volume_type           = (known after apply)
        }

      + ephemeral_block_device {
          + device_name  = (known after apply)
          + no_device    = (known after apply)
          + virtual_name = (known after apply)
        }

      + network_interface {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_index          = (known after apply)
          + network_interface_id  = (known after apply)
        }

      + root_block_device {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = (known after apply)
          + volume_type           = (known after apply)
        }

      + timeouts {}
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

------------------------------------------------------------------------

Note: You didn't specify an "-out" parameter to save this plan, so Terraform
can't guarantee that exactly these actions will be performed if
"terraform apply" is subsequently run.
```

Apply:

```
----snip----

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.

  Enter a value: yes

aws_instance.web: Creating...
aws_instance.web: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
aws_instance.web: Creation complete after 11s [id=i-0875a3e74f53ed82c]

Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Post creation, lets check plan:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-85 terraform]$ terraform plan
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

aws_instance.web: Refreshing state... [id=i-0875a3e74f53ed82c]

------------------------------------------------------------------------

No changes. Infrastructure is up-to-date.

This means that Terraform did not detect any differences between your
configuration and real physical resources that exist. As a result, no
actions need to be performed.
```

Now we delete the state file and import the resource:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-85 terraform]$ terraform import aws_instance.web i-0875a3e74f53ed82c
aws_instance.web: Importing from ID "i-0875a3e74f53ed82c"...
aws_instance.web: Import complete!
  Imported aws_instance
aws_instance.web: Refreshing state... [id=i-0875a3e74f53ed82c]

Import successful!

The resources that were imported are shown above. These resources are now in
your Terraform state and will henceforth be managed by Terraform.
```

Another plan:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-34-85 terraform]$ terraform plan
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but will not be
persisted to local or remote state storage.

aws_instance.web: Refreshing state... [id=i-0875a3e74f53ed82c]

------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
-/+ destroy and then create replacement

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_instance.web must be replaced
-/+ resource "aws_instance" "web" {
        ami                          = "ami-0bbc25e23a7640b9b"
      ~ arn                          = "arn:aws:ec2:eu-west-1:341009493741:instance/i-0875a3e74f53ed82c" -> (known after apply)
      ~ associate_public_ip_address  = true -> (known after apply)
      ~ availability_zone            = "eu-west-1b" -> (known after apply)
      ~ cpu_core_count               = 1 -> (known after apply)
      ~ cpu_threads_per_core         = 2 -> (known after apply)
      - disable_api_termination      = false -> null
      - ebs_optimized                = false -> null
        get_password_data            = false
      + host_id                      = (known after apply)
      ~ id                           = "i-0875a3e74f53ed82c" -> (known after apply)
      ~ instance_state               = "running" -> (known after apply)
        instance_type                = "t3.medium"
      + ipv6_address_count           = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_addresses               = (known after apply) # forces replacement
      + key_name                     = (known after apply)
      - monitoring                   = false -> null
      ~ network_interface_id         = "eni-077ae2820afc460a7" -> (known after apply)
      + password_data                = (known after apply)
      + placement_group              = (known after apply)
      ~ primary_network_interface_id = "eni-077ae2820afc460a7" -> (known after apply)
      ~ private_dns                  = "ip-172-31-2-15.eu-west-1.compute.internal" -> (known after apply)
      ~ private_ip                   = "172.31.2.15" -> (known after apply)
      ~ public_dns                   = "ec2-34-255-30-73.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply)
      ~ public_ip                    = "34.255.30.73" -> (known after apply)
      ~ security_groups              = [
          - "default",
        ] -> (known after apply)
        source_dest_check            = true
      ~ subnet_id                    = "subnet-25d0f941" -> (known after apply)
      - tags                         = {
          - "Backup" = "True"
        } -> null
      ~ tenancy                      = "default" -> (known after apply)
      + volume_tags                  = (known after apply)
      ~ vpc_security_group_ids       = [
          - "sg-12b9c774",
        ] -> (known after apply)

      - credit_specification {
          - cpu_credits = "unlimited" -> null
        }

      + ebs_block_device {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_name           = (known after apply)
          + encrypted             = (known after apply)
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + snapshot_id           = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = (known after apply)
          + volume_type           = (known after apply)
        }

      + ephemeral_block_device { # forces replacement
          + device_name  = (known after apply)
          + no_device    = (known after apply)
          + virtual_name = (known after apply)
        }

      + network_interface {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_index          = (known after apply)
          + network_interface_id  = (known after apply)
        }

      ~ root_block_device {
          ~ delete_on_termination = true -> (known after apply)
          ~ iops                  = 100 -> (known after apply)
          ~ volume_id             = "vol-0c46eb9d028b04d9a" -> (known after apply)
          ~ volume_size           = 8 -> (known after apply)
          ~ volume_type           = "gp2" -> (known after apply)
        }

        timeouts {}
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

Comment: It looks like a bug in the provider. You should raise this on the issue tracker: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues

Comment: Have submitted bug report. https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/9279

Comment: I am using Terraform 0.11.14 and tested same. but there is no problem in my case. what version do you use?

Comment: This is on 0.12.3

Comment: Came here with the same question.  For me it was solved by replacing the `security_groups` with `vpc_security_group_ids`